# Is there a way to update custom CSS variables with out creating dom Node?

Tags: javascript, css

Most of the times custom css variables are defined in the :root and can be later changed by using documentElement.setStyleProperty(--var-name, value).

Is there a way to update the css variables on a class where the dom node that containing that class, gets attached to body on fly?

Comment: What do you mean, by attaching the dom node? Where do you want to attach it to?

Comment: OP probably wants to change css variable without accessing any dom element

Comment: Do you mean [`setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) instead of `setStyleProperty`?

Comment: Your title states **"...with out creating dom Node"** and your question states **"where the dom node...gets attached to body on fly"**. These seem to contradict each other. What am I missing?